# How do I map Slick results to a different data structure?

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I've just started using Slick and I did a simple hello world project with posts and comments.

**I'd like to have the following data structure:**

```
Seq[(Post, Option[Seq[Comment]])]
```

Then I could iterate over the comments like so:

```
 @for(p <- posts) {
       @for(c <- posts.comments)  {
           @comment.title 
       }
 }
```

This is my Query:

```
 def allWithComments = {


    val q = for {
      (p, c) <- Posts join Comments on (_.id === _.postsId)
    } yield (p,c) // do here something fancy and map the result 



    db.run(q.result)

  }
```

The query returns the following structure right now:

```
Seq[(models.Post, models.Comment)]
```

Answer (score 0):

from `Seq[(models.Post, models.Comment)]` to `Seq[(Post, Option[Seq[Comment]])]` you may use the following:

```
(qResult groupBy (_._1) map { case (k,v) => (k, Option((v map (_._2)).toSeq)) }).toSeq
```

Comment: Where does that qResult come from ?

Comment: `qResult` is `db.run(q.result)`

Comment: Could you please post the whole method body with your solution included ? , I'm a little bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

I think the variable s below represents the structure of your "Posts join Comments on (_.id === _.postsId)" query. To get all the comments for a post you can do the operation on the next line.

```
val s = List((1,"sam"),(2,"s"),(1,"a"),(3,"sadk"))
s.groupBy(_._1).map({case (p,c) => (p,c.map(_._2))}).toSeq //ArrayBuffer((2,List(s)), (1,List(sam, a)), (3,List(sadk)))
```

Comment: I don't understand, what's with that s ?

Comment: Its just a sample datastructure which I think resembles your join query. You can consider the first value of the tuples to be post ids and the second value as comments. Am just showing a way to transform from that data structure to the one you want.

Comment: Same goes here: 
 
Could you please post the whole method body with your solution included ? , I'm a little bit confused

Comment: Ok, I am not familiar with Slick but is the q value in your code returning a list of tuples like this: List((Post1, Comment1), (Post1, Comment2), (Post2, Comment1), (Post3, Comment3))   ? If so, then `val s = Posts join Comments on (_.id === _.postsId); s.groupBy(_._1).map({case (p,c) => (p,c.map(_._2))}).toSeq`    will give you the datastructure you want.